# Installing MySQLDB on Python 2.7.3 under CentOS

Tags: python, mysql, centos

I need to install Python 2.7 on a machine, from source, alongside the existing version on the machine (2.4). I have compiled and installed Python successfully, but when I try to run a script calling the MySQLDB module, it throws the following error:

```
[root@the-node1 bin]# interactive_recording_archive.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/interactive_recording_archive.py", line 8, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as mdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

I have tried installing MySQLDB using the easy-install script but this fails to find any module by that name. I have MySQL installed and working on the machine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package is called [`MySQL-python`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4):

```
easy_install MySQL-python
```

Do check the [installation requirements](https://raw.github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/master/INSTALL); you have python and setuptools, but you need the `mysql-devel` package too.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks, I think I just hit that issue you mentioned in your edit - I don't have mysql-devel installed and when I try to install there seems to be a conflict with mysql-server on that machine, so I need to resolve that first. Is it possible to install MySQL-python without mysql-devel installed somehow?

Comment: @btongeorge: You need the MySQL client library headers. Without those, there is not enough information for the compiler to be able to *use* the client libraries. On CentOS, those headers are part of `mysql-devel`.

Comment: is it possible to just install the headers somehow though?

Comment: That's what you install `mysql-devel` for, that's the package with the headers. Compiling MySQL from source is the other method to get those headers, I guess.

Comment: I am a noob on centOS as compared to  debian...this worked like a charm on centOS server!!!